# my oracle db won't open please help

Tags: oracle, restore

This is what happens when I try to query as DBA:

---

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Nov 10 22:28:00 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: sys as sysdba  
Enter password:

Connected to:  
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> select count(*) from dba_users;

select count(*) from dba_users  
                     *   
ERROR at line 1:   ORA-01219: database not open: queries allowed on fixed tables/views only


SQL> alter database open;

alter database open  
*   
ERROR at line 1:   ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kcratr_nab_less_than_odr], [1], [824], [95], [98], [], [], [], [],
> [], [], []
```

---

please help to restore my db...

Comment: You should post the last 1,000 lines of your alert log file. It would also help for you to give some background on what was changed before this issue came up. Did you upgrade recently, apply a patch, change a system variable? You may end up needing to create an SR with Oracle to have them help you resolve the issue. But it is not clear from the ORA-00600 error what the issue is. You may also want to try: recover database until cancel using backup controlfile; AUTO recover database until cancel using backup controlfile; CANCEL alter database open resetlogs;

Comment: Hi there, I think there is a problem with your restore procedure.
A little google search lead me to this post [link](http://dbataj.blogspot.be/2011/06/alter-database-open-fails-with-ora.html)

Answer (score 1):

ORA-600 errors are usually bad news. [ORA-600 on OraFAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-00600).
If this is an environment you or anyone else cares about I recommend:
1) Opening an [Oracle service request](http://support.oracle.com)
2) Find your organizations DBA and engage them *immediately*
3) Dig those backups out because you may have a significant corruption of RDBMS binaries or data.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check your alert log file

Search for "ORA-" so you will be able to check errors on alert

Search on support.oracle if there is a patch that corrects that specific issue.

To check your current patching version open a command promp and type: opatch lsinv